# Setting alpha of drawable through xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-drawable

Can we set the alpha of drawable for its disable state through XML? For example by using android:state_disable.

Comment: question is not clear. please mention your correct requirement, then we may help you. We can disable a view (button, image button, etc.), it contains drawables. why to set alpha to drawable to disable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually we cant set alpha for drawable instead you should use this
setAlpha(int alpha)
Specify an alpha value for the drawable.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution, hope someone finds this useful. Yes, this is and old post, but posts like this need a answer that works today since they show up when you search.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <bitmap android:alpha="@integer/disabled_alpha" android:src="@drawable/item"/>
    <item/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Drawable card_water_wave = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_back);
card_water_wave.setAlpha(150);
```

Answer (score -1):

See my answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29078730/562365

Basically you can use the alpha of a BitmapDrawable and then use that drawable in your selector.